# Adding onLeave to fullpage.js

Tags: fullpage.js

I'm using fullpage.js and VSCode, when i add the `onLeave` callback, the color coding isn't turning it to blue, which means the code's been entered incorrectly. Have looked at many doc's, looks right to me, why is `onLeave` staying yellow? Thanks.

[image: 'scrollOverflow' is blue and works, but 'onLeave' is yellow and doesn't work]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not worry about the colours :)
Probably it is because properties containing a function have a different color than object properties containing a value.

It happens to me as well, see this image below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Alvaro, now i can eliminate thinking there's an error with the 'onLeave' event trigger, and get back to animations. Have followed this tut for animating (https://slicejack.com/animating-fullpage-js-content/). But the content animates everytime when .active class is triggered on section. How do i make animations just run once on initial scroll down? Thanks.

Comment: Can you accept the answers so others who come here knows this is the right one?
Thanks!